# .Net desktop application gives following error message DBNETLIB Connectionopen SecDoClientHandShake SSL Security Error

Tags: .net, tls1.2

.Net desktop application gives following error message DBNETLIB Connectionopen SecDoClientHandShake SSL Security Error.
SQL Database is connected and the change in database is just adding a NDF, after adding the file, application gives error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CVxO.png)

Need to have solution and assistance of this error

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_ at all. Instead you should add a tag for the dbms you're using. Could be <sql-server> perhaps?